# Optimize data import to MS Access 2016

Tags: microsoft-access, import

I am having a problem where I attempt to import a file to Access, but the import process bogs down and Access crashes. I am doing this in a desktop environment, and must use a specific desktop for it: “use a real tool” is simply not an option (much as I wish it was!), and I cannot install anything new on the desktop. I do not have admin access to the desktop.

So: I have a data download to an Excel spreadsheet, which needs to end up in a single Access table. I can pare the data file down to ~85 MB (~360k rows), which is still too large for import to succeed. I *can* open it in Excel. Given the same dataset, how can I minimize the resources needed to import it?

I have already tried freeing up as much memory as possible, which has previously worked with smaller files (didn’t work). I have also tried saving in various Excel formats (different times to crash, but didn’t work). I have searched for answers online, but have not found anything.

I also tried linking the Excel sheet as a data source (crashed before defining fields) and setting it up as a data object (failed due to lack of admin privileges).

My Cinderella-answer here would be something like an alternate import method or a way to save from Excel to a more efficiently-importable file format.

Comment: I'm not an Access guy, but based on Excel's inability to work well with anything other than Excel or a wizard who has mastered the dark arts, I suggest you export the excel file as a .csv, [split it into smaller files](https://stephan.io/split-a-csv-in-windows-powershell/) (such as 100k records per file or lower if you want), and import the smaller files individually.

Comment: There are tons of ways to insert data in Access using an Excel file. I generally recommend doing it using a query executed non-transactionally (using DAO or a macro with transactions disabled). That should not use much memory. You can see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49283984/7296893) for reference, you want the inverse of that.

Comment: @ErikA oh, interesting! I’ll try that on Monday.

Comment: You could also try saving the excel file as a .csv.